# How do I get notified that my azure endpoint has been removed from the load-balanced set

Tags: azure, endpoint, probe

I have 3 ubuntu Vm's configured (They are not websites but configured as a cloud service) with http endpoints in a load-balanced set. This is working really well with the probe configured to check every 15 secs on port 80. When the url does not return a status of 200 it gets removed from the load-balanced set until the next time that it returns a status of 200. I have used the webPortal to configure the endpoints and probe settings.

When the unhealthy instances is taken out of the load-balanced set I would like to be informed (via email preferable) of the situation so that I can fix the issue.

Comment: Why would your endpoint be "removed"?  That seems like something you'd do in the portal and you should know when you do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: The endpoints are not removed. Just the unhealthy instances are taken off of the load balancer. As for whether you can get notified when this happens - mm, no, there is not such service yet in Azure.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I updated my post to be more specific that it is removed from the load-balanced set.

Comment: what criteria does the load balancer use to determine "unhealthy"?  I think you'll have to run something to check that independant of the load-balancer.